# jquery how to handle missing fields in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, youtube-api

I am using ajax to get information from youtube videos.
Some videos include a geoloation, and some do not.
So when I request the lat and long and they are not included in the video I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined`.

My question is how can I modify my ajax call to handle both situations when there is a geolocation and when it is not included in the response?

my ajax call looks like this:

```
  $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+tubeVideoID+'?v=2&alt=jsonc',function(data,status,xhr){
    var thumbnail = data.data.thumbnail.sqDefault;
    var title = data.data.title;
    lat = data.data.geoCoordinates.latitude;
    lon = data.data.geoCoordinates.longitude;
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to test for `undefined`

```
 $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+tubeVideoID+'?v=2&alt=jsonc',function(data,status,xhr){
    var thumbnail = data.data.thumbnail.sqDefault;
    var title = data.data.title;
    if(data.data.geoCoordinates != undefined) {
        lat = data.data.geoCoordinates.latitude;
        lon = data.data.geoCoordinates.longitude;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You just test data.data.geoCoordinates !== undefined, hope this helps